# How to set Ruby SSL method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I am running Ruby 1.9.3, and trying to get either `HTTPClient v 2.3.2` or `OpenSSL::SSL::Socket` to use a different https method than SSLv3 by default. Thanks to the POODLE vulnerability many of the APIs we connect to are refusing SSLv3 connections and I need to change to TLSv1 without patching multiple gems.

How would I go about setting a default SSL method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = :TLSv1
```

If you're running in a Rails context, you should put the above line of code into an initializer (/config/initializers/openssl.rb).